# problema con la personalización de un encabezado en TCPDF en scriptcase

Tags: php, tcpdf

Tengo un problema con la personalización de un encabezado en tcpdf. Necesito mostrar una imagen como URL en el encabezado y además de esto estoy agregando una descripción al encabezado, los estoy mostrando por medio de etiquetas html, todos los datos provienen de base de datos, pero si inserto la imagen no me inserta la descripción en el pdf, pasa lo mismo al contrario, si inserta la descripción no muestra la imagen,

Acá dejo el código. El código inicia con la clase MYPDF que es el header personalizado heredando de tcpdf:

```
    <?php

    require_once('tcpdf.php');

    class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    
    protected $img;
    protected $descripcion;
    
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $img='';
        $descripcion='';
    }
    
    public function Header() {
        $image_file = $this->getmgHeader();
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
        // Title
        // $descr = $this->$descripcion;
        // $y = $this->getY();
        $html='<img src="'.$this->getmgHeader().'" width="200" height="80">';
        $this->writeHTMLCell(80, '', '', '', $html, 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);
        $desc='<p border="1" style="width: 45; font-size: 50%; padding: 15px; font: 50% sans-serif; border-radius: 2px;">
                    '.$this->getdescripcion().'
            </p>';
        // $this->writeHTMLCell(80, '', '', 60, $y, 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);
        $this->MultiCell(7, 5, '', 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true);
        // $this->MultiCell(95, 5, $this->getDescripcion(), 0, 'R', 0, 0, '', '', true);
        $this->writeHTMLCell(95, '', '', '', $desc, 0, 0, 0, true, 'R', true);
        // $this->Cell(95, 15, $this->getdescripcion(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    }
    
    public function setimgHeader($imghead){
        $this->$img=$imghead;
    }
    
    public function getmgHeader(){
            return $this->$img;
    }
    
    public function setDescripcion($desc){
        $this->$descripcion=$desc;
    }
    
    public function getDescripcion(){
            return $this->$descripcion;
    }
    
    }
```

y por ultimo el código en el blanco donde instancia la clase que cree y el envío los datos al set y get, el dataset [0] [3] contiene la url de la imagen y el otro dataset[0][4] contiene la descripción.

```
    $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    $pdf->setDescripcion({Dataset[0][4]});
    $pdf->setimgHeader({Dataset[0][3]});
```

si alguno le ha pasado este problema como lo ha solucionado? ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El código se comparte como texto por la misma razón que NO te vamos a responder con imágenes: usar código desde imágenes es imposible, se pueden omitir errores que tú tengas, replicar tu problema se hace más difícil, los más viejos no vemos bien el código, etc. Por favor, edita tu pregunta usando el enlace Editar que está justo debajo y comparte tu código como texto.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, copio mi código